# What came first, sequence or $\epsilon-\delta$ criterium for limit?

Tags: real-analysis, math-history

I find in many places that first came the sequence criterion, on Cauchy's book "Cours d'analyse" but I am not sure. Does any body know anything about that?

Thank you!

Comment: Depends on what you mean by a definition and how rigorous you expect the statement to be with respect to modern understanding.  Sequential limits are almost certainly more primitive, and were understood (in some sense) by the Greeks. Consider, for example, Archimedes method of determining $\pi$, or the arguments that follow from Zeno's paradoxes.  The $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ formalism is much more recent. It has a late-19th early-20th C vibe to me, and probably doesn't predate the formalism of a "function", which (to my recollection) is largely due to Fourier (late-18th, early-19th C).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by sequence criteria? Do you mean $\epsilon$-$N$ vs. $\epsilon$-$\delta$?

Comment: @Xander so according to what you are saying, the definition with sequences came first?

Comment: @anakhronizein exactly, that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$ iff, for every sequence $(x_n)\in D_f\setminus \{a\}$, st $x_n\to a$, implies that $f(x_n)\to L$.

Comment: Are you sure that is the definition Cauchy used? If I recall correctly, his definition effectively amounts to $\epsilon$-$\delta$ which he uses more conspicuously in proofs of statements regarding limits.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it may well belong on the History of Science and Mathematics SE.

Answer (score 0):

The [$\varepsilon$-$\delta$ formulation of limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit) (Wikipedia) was anticipated faintly by Fermat, used implicitly by Cauchy, and formalized by Bolzano in 1817.  As Xander Henderson indicated in the comments, the *notion* of a [sequence limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence) (Wikipedia again)—as $n \to \infty$, for instance—is older: anticipated by Archimedes in his method of exhaustion.  However, its formalism dates also to Bolzano (in 1816), but it was apparently not much noticed, and it was reformulated by Weierstrass in the 1870s.

See the "History" section of either Wikipedia article for more details.